# Store static Content on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, store

I was wondering what is the best way to store static content for my app.
E.g. a list of products (name, photos, price, url).

Maybe s.o. can direct to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Core Data is the best way , and you should use that.

Here's a link to Apple's Docs ( [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) )

Also theres a good discussion in Jeff Lamarche's blog in this [post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/12/superdb-core-data-app-with-sections.html)

A good thing to check for, would be Jeff's book "[More iPhone 3 Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022505X)".

Comment: Thanks, let see if we can use this with three20

Answer (score 0):

You can store everything in a SQLite database file which would be provided as a resource in your app.  But it is of course better to let Core Data read that file for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think both Core Data and SQLite are too heavy duty for what you want. Unless you have a large list of products, you should store them in a plist. The setup is minimal and accessing it is far easier than any of the other solutions. It's ideal for a small amount of static information and very easy to edit later.

Here's a tutorial on using plists:

http://humblecoder.blogspot.com/2009/05/iphone-tutorial-storing-and-retrieving.html

Comment: Core Data is not heavy at all and is a far superior option than using a plist.

Comment: @Marcus S.Zarra I 100% agree, plist is often used to save application preferences or other kind of really small stuff. Of course you could use it to save a lot of stuff, but it wasn't really designed for that.

Comment: I'm not saying that a plist should be used to store a large amount of stuff, but if you have a list of 10 items with no need to change them, why not? It's ideal for a beginner (minimal setup and learning) and simple to change the values. I think that the OP has only been learning Cocoa for a couple of months and Core Data would be too complicated to tackle at this stage. (BTW, when I said "heavy duty", I meant that it's overkill, not that it would make the program run slower).