# Add static content to an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, core-data

I already saw an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260982/store-static-content-on-iphone), but it didn't really answer my question. I want to have some static content in my app, such as section names. I want to store this data in Core Data, but I can't add this data. I know how to add data when retrieving data from the internet, for example, but I don't know how to add data manually.
If not in Core Data, where can I add this information?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data in a plist file. You can find an example [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/02/14/loading-data-from-plist-files/) for reading data from a plist.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to store section names for your tables in Core Data? Core Data is for application data, usually that the user has some involvement in creating, or at the very least is tabular and/or subject to change. Purely static content doesn't need to be stored in Core Data.

Comment: Maybe the "section names" was a bad example, but my question is: if I want to have an app that has all its content "built in" in the app, which method do I use? As you mentioned, Core Data is for application data which can be modified, so which alternative there is? Only a plist file?